# how to select distinct columns in join querys

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to select distinct GTIM  column values from data table using join of two tables.
    here is my query..

```
SELECT TOP (9) Tracking.LAMI,
  Tracking.LGMI,
  Tracking.SPED,
  Tracking.BAT_ADC,
  Tracking.GTIM,
  Tracking.MAIN_BACKUP,
  Tracking.PULSE_CTR,
  Tracking.NOST,
  Tracking.IGST,
  Tracking.COND_INPUTS,
  Tracking.FUEL_ADC,
  Tracking.M,
  Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber
FROM Tracking
INNER JOIN Vehicles_Device_Rel
  ON Tracking.M = Vehicles_Device_Rel.Device_ID
WHERE (Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber = 'test')
ORDER BY GTIM DESC
```

Sample output:

```
12.988000 77.68367400 6 543 2013-08-30 17:26:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test    
12.918800 77.65367400 6 543 2013-08-30 17:25:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test 
12.968800 77.65367400 4 543 2013-08-30 17:25:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test    
12.891880 77.65367400 6 543 2013-08-30 17:24:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is for all the columns in the select clause, which means all columns combined will be used to get distinct rows. `TOP X` will only select the number of rows mentioned in `X`.

Answer (score 0):

This selects the distinct values.  Is it what you want?

```
SELECT distinct Tracking.GTIM
FROM Tracking
INNER JOIN Vehicles_Device_Rel
  ON Tracking.M = Vehicles_Device_Rel.Device_ID
WHERE (Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber = 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join your current query with a `SELECT DISTINCT GTIM FROM TRACKING`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (9) Tracking.LAMI,
  Tracking.LGMI,
  Tracking.SPED,
  Tracking.BAT_ADC,
  Tracking.GTIM,
  Tracking.MAIN_BACKUP,
  Tracking.PULSE_CTR,
  Tracking.NOST,
  Tracking.IGST,
  Tracking.COND_INPUTS,
  Tracking.FUEL_ADC,
  Tracking.M,
  Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber
FROM Tracking
INNER JOIN Vehicles_Device_Rel
  ON Tracking.M = Vehicles_Device_Rel.Device_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT GTIM FROM TRACKING) T ON T.GTIM = Tracking.GTIM
WHERE (Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber = 'test')
ORDER BY Tracking.GTIM DESC
```

I assume this is the query you are looking for.

Comment: hi Radu gheorghiu, when i executive above modified query again i am getting duplicates of GTIM values..

Comment: @Gajulapalle.rajesh You might have duplicates, but that is because you might have records for different vehicles logged at the same time (the same GTIM, I assume GTIM contains time values, if not please correct me).

Comment: @Gajulapalle.rajesh Also, some sample data after running your query will be useful.

Comment: 12.9880000000 77.6836740000 6 543 2013-08-30 17:26:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test
12.9188000000 77.6536740000 6 543 2013-08-30 17:25:00.000 1 0.00 10  1 99 10 10 test
12.9688000000 77.6536740000 4 543 2013-08-30 17:25:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test
12.8918800000 77.6536740000 6 543 2013-08-30 17:24:00.000 1 0.00 10 1 99 10 10 test

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
      Tracking.LAMI,
      Tracking.LGMI,
      Tracking.SPED,
      Tracking.BAT_ADC,
      Tracking.GTIM,
      Tracking.MAIN_BACKUP,
      Tracking.PULSE_CTR,
      Tracking.NOST,
      Tracking.IGST,
      Tracking.COND_INPUTS,
      Tracking.FUEL_ADC,
      Tracking.M,
      Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber,
      RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tracking.GTIM 
                                ORDER BY SomeColumn)            -- your choice
    FROM Tracking
    INNER JOIN Vehicles_Device_Rel
      ON Tracking.M = Vehicles_Device_Rel.Device_ID
    WHERE (Vehicles_Device_Rel.VehicalNumber = 'test')
  )
SELECT TOP (9) *
FROM cte
WHERE RowN = 1
ORDER BY GTIM DESC ;
```